# Paypal Simple payment SDK not giving control over failed transactions

Tags: android, paypal

I am stuck in a problem while using Paypal simple payment SDK downloaded from github.
The problem is :

While making a payment if payment is succeeded the SDK gives the PAY-id with which I can get more information about payment with Rest APIs with the following code.

```
public void onBuyPressed(View pressed) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(SampleActivity.this, PaymentActivity.class);

    // send the same configuration for restart resiliency
    intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);

    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);

    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT);
}
```

This gives me the PAY-Id in onActivityResult method.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT) {

            PaymentConfirmation confirm = data
                    .getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
            if (confirm != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, confirm.toJSONObject().toString());
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonOBJ = new JSONObject(confirm
                            .toJSONObject().toString(4));
                    String PayID = jsonOBJ.getJSONObject("response")
                            .getString("id");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "PaymentConfirmation info received from PayPal",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

But whenever a payment fails, SDK did not give the error code to me SDK handles itself and show a popup illustrating the error even "onActivityResult" method never calls in case of failure.

Now I have to send the Logs for cause of payment failure to the server.
I am unable to do so.

> Alternate SDKs used:
>
> - I have also used Paypal ExpressCheckout but it was not good looking as this application is on android.
> - I have also used Paypal MPL but it has no functionality to pay as a  guest (Credit/debit card payment).
>
> Can anyone help me to get the failure logs which can be sent to server.

Comment: Does anyone have the answer of my query as the build is in production now.

Answer (score 0):

The Android SDK is designed to display user correctable errors directly, since PayPal is in the best position to give feedback about what has happened if the end user can fix it.

However, if something else is happening, some debug info is printed to the Android system log.

Comment: how can i get that debug info from the logs as i have to send that logs to the server